# Problems getting my ActionModeBar(?) to overlap support toolbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design, android-toolbar

I have been trying to get my app to look more material(ized) with the help of app compat v21, I have replaced my regular actionbar with the support toolbar, and changed my theme to **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** this works great! However, when I longpress an item in my gridview and my actionmode bar (is that what they are called?) shows up for multi select it shows above the toolbar.

I want it to overlap the toolbar, the same way it did with my old regular actionbar. I have tried to find a solution here, and have found multiple sources saying to add         **true**

This does not work for me, i have tried both with the android: prefix and without, but still I get the same result. My activity extends **ActionBarActivity** and I have put:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

In my onCreate. I feel like I have tried anything but I get the same result regardless.

I guess I better show some code:

My main layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?window_bg_default"
    >
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@color/text_darkgray"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/adView"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<include layout="@layout/navdrawer" />
```

My styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/twee_orange_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/twee_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/twee_blue_light</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.Actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/twee_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Overflow</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_home</item>
    <item name="card_bg_default">@drawable/img_bg_card</item>
    <item name="window_bg_default">@drawable/window_background</item>
    <item name="card_episode_name">@color/nextepisodegray</item>
    <item name="card_episode_number">@color/twee_black</item>
    <item name="button_bg">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="button_watched">@drawable/ic_watched_inactive</item>
    <item name="text_default">@color/text_slightlydarkgray</item>
    <item name="text_default_header">@color/text_darkergray</item>
    <item name="text_season_separator">@color/black</item>
    <item name="drawer_background">@color/drawer_background</item>
    <item name="drawer_list_background">@color/drawer_list_background</item>
    <item name="card_bg_default_color">@color/drawer_list_background</item>
    <item name="twee_divider">@color/divider_default</item>
    <item name="card_header_default">@drawable/img_bg_cardtop_header</item>
    <item name="checkbox_watched">@drawable/checkbox_watched</item>
    <item name="card_middle_bg">@drawable/background_listitem_default</item>
</style>
```

My toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:background="@color/twee_orange_light"
 app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
 app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
 android:elevation="8dp" />
```

My navdrawer:¨

```
<se.ja1984.twee.Activities.Views.ScrimInsetsScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_wrapper"
    android:background="?drawer_background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:insetForeground="#4000"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:background="@drawable/img_navdrawer_header"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/navbar_top"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/lnrProfileChooser"
            >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutImage"
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                    >
                    <se.ja1984.twee.utils.RoundedImageView
                        style="@style/Twee_Cast_Photo"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imgUser"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_no_cast"/>

                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/traktWrapper"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        >
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/background"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/trakt_background"
                            />
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/imgTraktLogo"
                            android:layout_width="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_trakt_logo"
                            />
                    </FrameLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>

                <it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView
                    android:id="@+id/profiles"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/Twee_Profile_Displayname"
                        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
                        android:text="@string/profile_notsignedin_displayname"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Xxxx hours well spent"
                        style="@style/Twee_Profile_Timewasted"
                        android:id="@+id/txtTimeWasted"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtUsername" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navdrawer_items_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</se.ja1984.twee.Activities.Views.ScrimInsetsScrollView>
```

The trained eyes might see that I have borrowed the ScrimInsetScrollView from the IOSched app, but I don't think that matters.

And here's an image of the monsterosity!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue myself!

The problem is that I ran my super.onCreate() to late in my onCreate method.

I moved it to the top of my method, and now it works great!